# How to display procedurally created rooms as a schematic map?

Tags: procedural-generation, maps

In most games, a map can be generated by essentially doing a "top-down" view of the specific area. This will accurately show the size and positioning of any rooms, as well as how they connect.There might be special icons for stairs, doors, etc.

In a game I am working on I am intentionally keeping some concepts rather loose. The map is not there so much to display distance between rooms or the relative size of rooms between each other, but just to most clearly show the connections between the rooms.

The easiest real-life example I can show is an electronic schematic.

[image: Schematic]

Now, I only know some of the symbols on there, but in this case you might just substitute them for various rooms. You can easily imagine then that this layout could have many actual physical representations. A connection could be a door, but it could also be stairs or even an abstract "border" between two regions.

I currently generate "rooms", without size or even position. I then assign them connections. Not exactly "random" connections but I am still playing with the generation so I don't have any hard rules at this time.

The task I am having a difficult time with is: How do I take these rooms with connections and arrange them in such a way to maximize clarity of which rooms connect to which?

Comment: What specifically do you want the schematic to do that a top down blueprint or floor plan doesn't? Do you want a graph (i.e. nodes & edges) representation?

Comment: The problem is more that the top-down blueprint reveals too much information. Ideally, rooms would be nodes with single lines representing which connect to which in a manner that makes all connections appear equidistant. Simply enforcing those rules is likely to come up with overlap and I'm not sure how to handle that or other likely problems.

Comment: Rather than "reveals too much info" I should have said, "requires too much info" since at no point do I actually have a blueprint or any sense of size of rooms or which rooms are located in what direction of each other.

Comment: This question describes a very large general field of study called [Graph Drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing). We won't be able to give a full description of all the options available to you in the scope of a single answer, nor single out one as the best. I'd recommend you do some preliminary research on the topic of graph drawing, pick a strategy that suits your style and goals, and try implementing it - then if you run into any trouble, you can ask a more specific question about the specific method & implementation you're using.

Comment: Additional constraints would help narrow the search for an algorithm. If an electronic schematic style is okay, look for those. If your graph is planar, search for visibility representations of planar orthogonal graphs.

Comment: It seems like you already know what to do :3